# Subscripts in axis text ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript, ggpubr

I am relatively new to R, and as a chemist I need to use subscripts quite often. In particular, for example in this graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugF2B.png)

The code I am using is the following:

```
ggline(my_data, x = "ATPS", y = "PRYBSA", color = "Pretreatment",
       add = "mean_sd", size=1, ylim=c(0,105),
       palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), legend="right",
       ylab ="Protein recovery yield / %",error.plot = "errorbar") + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=24,face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=24),legend.text=element_text(size=22))
TukeyHSD(prybsa.aov, which = "ATPS")
```

The variable "ATPS" has three levels: Bet:2LA/K2HPO4, ChCl:2Urea/K2HPO4 and ChCl:2Urea/K3PO4, but I want them to appear with subscripts Bet:2LA/K<sub>2</sub>HPO<sub>4</sub>, ChCl:2Urea/K<sub>2</sub>HPO<sub>4</sub> and ChCl:2Urea/K<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub>.

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to `recode` your labels using `?plotmath` notation to add the subscripts. Then use e.g. `scales::label_parse` in `scale_x_discrete` to parse the math expressions:

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

my_data <- data.frame(
  ATPS = rep(c("Bet:2LA/K2HPO4", "ChCl:2Urea/K2HPO4", "ChCl:2Urea/K3PO4"), each = 2),
  Pretreatment = c("Mortar", "None"),
  PRYBSA = runif(10 * 6, 0, 100)
)

library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

my_data$ATPS <- dplyr::recode(
  my_data$ATPS,
  "Bet:2LA/K2HPO4" = "Bet:2*LA/K[2]*HPO[4]",
  "ChCl:2Urea/K2HPO4" = "ChCl:2*Urea/K[2]*HPO[4]",
  "ChCl:2Urea/K3PO4" = "ChCl:2*Urea/K[3]*PO[4]"
)

ggline(my_data,
  x = "ATPS", y = "PRYBSA", color = "Pretreatment",
  add = "mean_sd", size = 1, ylim = c(0, 105),
  palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
  legend = "right",
  ylab = "Protein recovery yield / %",
  error.plot = "errorbar"
) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())
```

[image]

A second and perhaps more lightweight approach would be to use [Unicode subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts):

```r
my_data$ATPS <- dplyr::recode(
  my_data$ATPS,
  "Bet:2LA/K2HPO4" = "Bet:2LA/K\u2082HPO\u2084",
  "ChCl:2Urea/K2HPO4" = "ChCl:2Urea/K\u2082HPO\u2084",
  "ChCl:2Urea/K3PO4" = "ChCl:2Urea/K\u2083*PO\u2084"
)

ggline(my_data,
       x = "ATPS", y = "PRYBSA", color = "Pretreatment",
       add = "mean_sd", size = 1, ylim = c(0, 105),
       palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
       legend = "right",
       ylab = "Protein recovery yield / %",
       error.plot = "errorbar"
)
```

[image]